# Error show in php if there is only one input blank

Tags: php, html, sql

If any any one of them are blank then show error message. But it is not working.I mean, if I any one between input and option remain empty then the error will show. One of them must be selected.

Here is [image: image of my form].

```
<?php include "head.htm";?>
<br>
<br>
<body bgcolor="#FEF5E7">
<title>Search Profile</title>

<form method="post" action="search.php">
    <input type="text"  placeholder="Enter Student's ID/Name" name="query" />
    <select name="BRANCH">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="Banani">Banani</option>
        <option value="RayerBazar">RayerBazar</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Find" name="completedsearch" />
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['completedsearch']))
{
    $term = $_POST['query'];
    $term1 = $_POST['BRANCH'];
    $mysql = mysql_connect("localhost","password","null");
    mysql_select_db("mydb");

    $qu = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `stu` WHERE STUDENTID LIKE '%{$term}%' OR STUDENTID LIKE '%{$term}%' OR BRANCH LIKE '%{$term1}%' OR STUDENTID LIKE '%{$term}%' "); //selects the row that contains ANYTHING like the submitted string
    $qu1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `stu` WHERE BRANCH LIKE '%{$term1}%'  ");

    if ($term  == "" || $term1  == "") {
      // no results
      echo '<a style="color:red;font-size: 30px;">Please Put Name OR ID Here</a><br><body  background="ghost.gif"   style="background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size: cover">';
    } else {
        echo "<table style='width:100%'>
                    <th style='width:10%;font-size:20px;border: 2px solid  red; '>Info ID</th>
                    <th style='width:20%;font-size:20px;border: 2px solid  red; '>School ID</th>
                    <th style='width:20%;font-size:20px;border: 2px solid  red; '>Name</th>
                    <th style='width:10%;font-size:20px;border: 2px solid  red; '>Class</th>
                    <th style='width:10%;font-size:20px;border: 2px solid  red; '>Shift</th>
                    <th style='width:10%;font-size:20px;border: 2px solid  red; '>Branch</th>
                    <th style='width:20%;font-size:20px;border: 2px solid  red; '>Search</th>
                    ";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qu))
       {
            echo "<tr><td style='width:10%;font-size:15px;border: 2px solid  blue;'><p style='text-slign: center;font-family: cursive;text-align: center'>";  
            echo $row['id'];
            echo "</p></td>";
            echo "<td style='width:20%;font-size:15px;border: 2px solid  blue;'><p style='text-slign: center;font-family: cursive;text-align: center'>";
            echo $row['STUDENTID'];
            echo "</p></td>";
            echo "<td style='width:20%;font-size:15px;border: 2px solid  blue;'><p style='text-slign: center;font-family: cursive;text-align: center'>";
            echo $row['STUDENTNAME'];
            echo "</p></td>";
            echo "<td style='width:10%;font-size:15px;border: 2px solid  blue;'><p style='text-slign: center;font-family: cursive;text-align: center'>";
            echo $row['CLASS'];
            echo "</p></td>";
            echo "<td style='width:10%;font-size:15px;border: 2px solid  blue;'><p style='text-slign: center;font-family: cursive;text-align: center'>";
            echo $row['SHIFT'];
            echo "</p></td>";
            echo "<td style='width:10%;font-size:15px;border: 2px solid  blue;'><p style='text-slign: center;font-family: cursive;text-align: center'>";
            echo $row['BRANCH'];
                   echo "</p></td>";
            echo " <td style='width:20%;font-size:15px;border: 2px solid  blue;'><p style='text-slign: center;font-family: cursive;text-align: center'><a href='id.php?id=";
            echo $row['id'];
            echo "'>Visit This Profile</a></p></td>";
        }

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qu1))
       {
            echo "<tr><td style='width:10%;font-size:15px;border: 2px solid  blue;'><p style='text-slign: center;font-family: cursive;text-align: center'>";  
            echo $row['id'];
            echo "</p></td>";
            echo "<td style='width:20%;font-size:15px;border: 2px solid  blue;'><p style='text-slign: center;font-family: cursive;text-align: center'>";
            echo $row['STUDENTID'];
            echo "</p></td>";
            echo "<td style='width:20%;font-size:15px;border: 2px solid  blue;'><p style='text-slign: center;font-family: cursive;text-align: center'>";
            echo $row['STUDENTNAME'];
            echo "</p></td>";
            echo "<td style='width:10%;font-size:15px;border: 2px solid  blue;'><p style='text-slign: center;font-family: cursive;text-align: center'>";
            echo $row['CLASS'];
            echo "</p></td>";
            echo "<td style='width:10%;font-size:15px;border: 2px solid  blue;'><p style='text-slign: center;font-family: cursive;text-align: center'>";
            echo $row['SHIFT'];
            echo "</p></td>";
            echo "<td style='width:10%;font-size:15px;border: 2px solid  blue;'><p style='text-slign: center;font-family: cursive;text-align: center'>";
            echo $row['BRANCH'];
            echo "</p></td>";
            echo " <td style='width:20%;font-size:15px;border: 2px solid  blue;'><p style='text-slign: center;font-family: cursive;text-align: center'><a href='id.php?id=";
            echo $row['id'];
            echo "'>Visit This Profile</a></p></td>";
        }
    }
}
?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Tip: `echo "<div>{$data['id']}</div>";`

Answer (score 0):

As you ask that if any one between input and option remain empty then the error will show than use

```
if(!empty($_POST['query']) || !empty($_POST['BRANCH']) ) {
   // one of them or both select
 } else {
   die("please select one of them ")
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Please prefer to use PDO or mysqli instead of this msql
if you want show error on first page instead of search.php than use Ajax

as you said than try this

```
if(empty($_POST['query']) && empty($_POST['BRANCH'])) {
     die ("Please select any one or both")
} else if (!empty($_POST['query']) && !empty($_POST['BRANCH']) {  

  // it mean user selected both than try to write your query whith And 
  // SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `student_id` LIKE '%$id%' AND `BRANCH` LIKE `$branch` 
}  else if (!empty($_POST['query'])) {
   // user only write in  text box 
   //SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `student_id` LIKE '%$id%'
  } else {
   //user choose select option 
   //SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE  `BRANCH` LIKE `%$branch%` 
  }
```

Comment: actually i need any one, not both, "must be select one"

Comment: @IceyEvan  Now i updated If you want to any one empty  than use  `or ||` in if function

Comment: @IceyEvan please explain more

Comment: @IceyEvan  explain again , you want to show error if  one of them empty or one of them  sholud be selected (mean error show when both are not selected)so you can  run the code

Comment: @IceyEvan  yes in your site without selecting  any one of them  result will displaying  than put you code if clause than see

Comment: I need, 2 option, any one can search by id/name or some one can check by only selecting option.... but select option is working but search option does not working

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['completedsearch'])){
   if(empty($_POST['query']) || empty($_POST['BRANCH'])) {
     echo "Show your error!"; 
   }else {
     //execute your code.
   }
}
```

Comment: actually i need any one, not both, "must be select one"

Comment: Please try this.
if(isset($_POST['completedsearch'])){
   if(!empty($_POST['query']) || !empty($_POST['BRANCH'])) {
      //execute your code.
   }else {
     echo "Show your error!";
   }
}